# How to restrict access to certain pages on to admin user in Django

Tags: django

I have created a Control Panel App to manage the newsletter of the project, so there are pages for which the admin can manage the newsletter, not the Django admin.

How can I restrict the access of these pages to be only to admin and show a 404 error if a normal user is trying to access the link?

I am looking for the most secure way to do this

Here is the newsletter app views.py

```
def control_newsletter(request):
    form = NewsletterCreationForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save()
        newsletter = Newsletter.objects.get(id=instance.id)

        if newsletter.status == "Published":
            subject = newsletter.subject
            body = newsletter.body
            from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
            for email in newsletter.email.all():
                send_mail(subject=subject, from_email=from_email, recipient_list=[
                          email.email], message=body, fail_silently=False)

    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    template = 'control_newsletter.html'
    return render(request, template, context)

def control_newsletter_list(request):
    newsletter = Newsletter.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(newsletter, 10)
    page = request.GET.get('page')

    try:
        items = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        items = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        items = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    index = items.number - 1
    max_index = len(paginator.page_range)
    start_index = index - 5 if index >= 5 else 0
    end_index = index + 5 if index <= max_index - 5 else max_index
    page_range = paginator.page_range[start_index:end_index]

    context = {
        "items": items,
        "page_range": page_range
    }
    template = "control_newsletter_list.html"
    return render(request, template, context)


def control_newsletter_detail(request, pk):
    newsletter = get_object_or_404(Newsletter, pk=pk)
    context = {
        "newsletter": newsletter,
    }
    template = "control_newsletter_detail.html"
    return render(request, template, context)


def control_newsletter_edit(request, pk):
    newsletter = get_object_or_404(Newsletter, pk=pk)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewsletterCreationForm(request.POST, instance=newsletter)

        if form.is_valid():
            newsletter = form.save()

            if newsletter.status == "Published":
                subject = newsletter.subject
                body = newsletter.body
                from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
                for email in newsletter.email.all():
                    send_mail(subject=subject, from_email=from_email, recipient_list=[
                        email.email], message=body, fail_silently=False)
            return redirect('control_panel:control_newsletter_detail', pk=newsletter.pk)
    else:
        form = NewsletterCreationForm(instance=newsletter)
    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    template = 'control_newsletter.html'
    return render(request, template, context)


def control_newsletter_delete(request, pk):
    newsletter = get_object_or_404(Newsletter, pk=pk)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewsletterCreationForm(request.POST, instance=newsletter)

        if form.is_valid():
            newsletter.delete()

            return redirect('control_panel:control_newsletter_list')
    else:
        form = NewsletterCreationForm(instance=newsletter)
    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    template = 'control_newsletter_delete.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

here are the urls.py

```
app_name = 'newsletters'

urlpatterns = [
    path('newsletter/', control_newsletter, name="control_newsletter"),
    path('newsletter-list/', control_newsletter_list,
         name="control_newsletter_list"),
    path('newsletter-detail/<int:pk>', control_newsletter_detail,
         name="control_newsletter_detail"),
    path('newsletter-edit/<int:pk>', control_newsletter_edit,
         name="control_newsletter_edit"),
    path('newsletter-delete/<int:pk>', control_newsletter_delete,
         name="control_newsletter_delete"),
]
```

and here is the models.py

```
class NewsletterUser(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Newsletter User"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

class Newsletter(models.Model):
    EMAIL_STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('Draft', 'Draft'),
        ('Published', 'Published')
    )
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    body = models.TextField()
    email = models.ManyToManyField(NewsletterUser)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=EMAIL_STATUS_CHOICES)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject
```

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually you can look at [Role Based Access Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control). What you want to do is define a set of roles and assign permission to those roles. These permissions can be about page access or any other action. When a person is assigned the role, he or she inherits the permissions associated. You can check if the role of the user has a certain permission or not and then decide to provide or deny access. So you can two roles for eg.

- Django Admin
- Application Admin

You can go on to define which pages can be accessed by whom and then develop your application is accordance to it.